# Efficient algorithms for computing combinatorial structure of a given polytope?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, convex-geometry, polytopes

Fix $n$. A convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as the nonempty, bounded intersection of finitely many closed half-spaces such that it has nonempty interior.

I'm given the list of vertices of a convex polytope. How can I determine which vertices are connected to which other vertices by edges, faces, ..., facets? I.e. the combinatorial structure of the polytope? I've reduced this problem to determining if a given point is in the convex hull of a list of other points.

Comment: You should not expect a super efficient algorithm, as an $n$-polytope with $2n$ vertices (e.g. the $n$-crosspolytope) can have $3^n$ faces that need to be enumerated. So you have exponential runtime anyways. Do you still want to know just any algorithm that can achieve this?

Comment: I have a provisional algorithm which inductively computes the facets of the convex hull of the first i points as i = 1,2,3,... What are some other ideas?

Comment: One initial thought: just compute the vertices that define facets. The vertex sets of the other faces are then all possible intersections of vertex sets of the facets.